# How to delete a specific paragraph in text file?

Tags: text-processing

I have this following html file.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>This is my page </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-8">
                 {% for post in posts %}
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="date">
                            <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<p>Hi there!</p>
<p>It works!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to delete everything inside the '**body**' tag with just only 1 command, how could i do that?

Comment: I assume the closing tag should be `</body>`.

Comment: @Guido Ah, my mistake. I edited it.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, if there is a string `</body>` in some commented out part of the file you're going to have problems if you use simple regex based matching.

Comment: Well, I forgot about that. I think it's best to delete based on line number, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using "perl"

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<body>.*<\/body>//s' <file
```

- Option `-0777` makes Perl read the file as a single line
- The `s/…//` substitution replaces the body tags and everything within. This works across line boundaries because of the option `-0777` in combination with the `s` modifier after the substitution.

To modify a file in-place, use

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/<body>.*<\/body>//s' -i file
```

Comment: I tried that command but it didn't work. My file still the same it was before.

Comment: @TheOne To change the file contents directly, see my updated answer.